# Microsoft Graph List places api not returning updated results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

Hello Microsoft Graph Team,

I am using Microsoft Graph Apis. I have added few rooms to the tenant but those are not reflected as part of response for List places api. However, findRooms api which is in Beta gives the updated response.

I am using the below api:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room (Production version)

The standard api gives response after aprrox 12-24 hours.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: What client are you using? Have you tried this on [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and got the same behavior?

Comment: @Danstan I have tried Graph Explorer, Postman both. It is not giving me updated results. After Adding a room, when i make a call to this api even in graph explorer it gives old result. After 12-24 hours the newly added room is shown in the result.